# ¿Cómo puedo ejecutar estos métodos en java?

Tags: java, android, api, volley

Estoy tratando de ejecutar los siguiente métodos en java al presionar un botón, el primero es una llamada a volley que se encarga de traer datos desde un API y el segundo se encarga de mostrar los datos obtenidos en los TextView de la pantalla. Se está presentando el siguiente problema, primero se ejecuta el método que se encarga de mostrar los datos y luego el que se encarga de traerlos.

Investigando un poco el problema, me pude dar cuenta que volley se ejecuta de manera asincrona, entonces permite realizar los demás procesos sin tener que esperar a que se ejecute la consulta.

Como primero se muestran los datos y luego se realiza la consulta, no me está mostrando los datos.

```
        ibtnBuscar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                final ConexionApi conexionApi = new ConexionApi();
                try {
                    conexionApi.consultarProducto(getApplicationContext(),V_URL_MON, tCodigoLeido.getText().toString());
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "En los datos", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    cargarDatos();
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } 
                //Se muestran los valores en la vista
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

En la misma pregunta está la solución: *Como primero se muestran los datos y luego se realiza la consulta, no me está mostrando los datos.* Entonces, tienes que mandar a pedir los datos (Volley)  y desde dentro del `response` de Volley mandar a mostrar los datos.

Por ejemplo, aquí vamos a imaginar que se una petición `GET` a una API que devuelve un JSON:

```
public void cargarDatos() {
    RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
    JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(
            Request.Method.GET, TU_URL, null,
            response -> {
                try {
                    /*
                       *Aquí tienes los datos en response
                       *puedes pasarlos a un método `mostrarDatos()
                       *o mostrarlos aquí mismo
                     */
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    /*Tratar error o mostrar un mensaje*/
                }
            },
            error -> {
                /*Tratar error o mostrar un mensaje*/
            }
    );

    jsonObjectRequest.setRetryPolicy(new DefaultRetryPolicy(
            MY_DEFAULT_TIMEOUT,
            DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_MAX_RETRIES,
            DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT));
    requestQueue.add(jsonObjectRequest);
    progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
}
```

Comment: El problema es que el método de cargarDatos() lo tengo en otra clase.

Comment: @CarlosDnl pues crea una instancia de esa clase e invoca el método: `LaClase mClase=new LaClase();` y luego: `mClase.cargarDatos();`